# Searching in mongo db using mongoose regex vs. text

Tags: mongodb, text, mongoose

Can anyone please explain the difference between:

```
db.collection.find({ $text: { $search: "dog cat" } })
```

and

```
Product.find({ "drug": { "$regex": "cols", "$options": "i" } })
```

When should we go for which one ?

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. But I have one more doubt. I am using the $text and using the $score projection to sort my results based on the relevance. But I need the feature of using matching partial string too like regex. Is there any way to use them both ?

Comment: you can use regex on field with text index. however if you are looking for best of both worlds, unfortunately its not supported yet. let's hope for good.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[$regex](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/regex/)

> Provides regular expression capabilities for pattern matching strings in queries. MongoDB uses Perl compatible regular expressions (i.e. “PCRE” ) version 8.36 with UTF-8 support.

[$text](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/text/)

> performs a text search on the content of the fields indexed with a [text index](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/index-text/).

---

For data

```
{ "_id" : 100, "sku" : "abc123", "description" : "Single line description." }
{ "_id" : 101, "sku" : "abc789", "description" : "First line\nSecond line" }
{ "_id" : 102, "sku" : "xyz456", "description" : "Many spaces before     line" }
{ "_id" : 103, "sku" : "xyz789", "description" : "Multiple\nline description" }
```

To search field `sku` which is single string value, could use `$regex`

```
db.products.find( { sku: { $regex: /^ABC/i } } )
```

Whereas to search field `description` which is text content value, could use `$text`, of course, we should build text index on `description` firstly.

```
db.products.find( { $text: { $search: "coffee" } } )
```

---

Why not only regex?

- `regular expressions` have their natural limitations because they lack any stemming functionality and cannot handle convenient search queries such as `“action -superhero”` in a trivial way.
- they cannot use traditional indexes which makes queries in large datasets really slow.

Here is one [link](https://comsysto.com/blog-post/mongodb-full-text-search-vs-regular-expressions) to compare them.

Answer (score 18):

Well, both regex and text search ($text) help you to search in text very efficiently. Both have their own advantages and disadvantages, But there are two clear distinctions

> **regex**

- Regex doesn't take advantage of indexes, unless you are searching in beginning of string using `^` operator.
- Regex allows you to search partial text. therefore .* and so many other patterns.
- Regex doesn't support stop or noise words.

> **$text**

text indexes in mongodb are really fast and should be preferred. However, MongoDB does not implement full featured text indexes. One main drawback is, it doesn't support partial match. e.g. if you are searching for cat, it will search only for cat and cats but not bobcat or caterpiller.

> Bottom line is if you are looking to implement feature like RDBMS `like` operator, '$text' will not help you (at least in current implementations of MongoDB, but in future it may change).

Comment: Hi, i tried to use both by something like this:
 
 db.products.find({ $text: { $search: { $regex: "test", $options: "i" } } }, {score : { $meta: "textScore" } }).sort( { score: { $meta: "textScore" } } )
 
 It throws an error
 
 Error: error: {
        "$err" : "Can't canonicalize query: BadValue $search needs a String",
        "code" : 17287
}
 
 Is there any way we can use both? I am new to mongo. Please help