# compare two strings in mongoose with regex

Tags: javascript, regex, mongoose

I have a csv for data to upload in db. But I need to insert on conditions. So I have two tables, one is in which csv data is uplaoded and second is from which I compare the field.
for csv there is a field called 'sku' and from csv its 13th row, r[13], so what I do is,

```
var sku = r[13]
            casesizemodel.findOne({model:new RegExp(sku,"i")},function(err,doc){ });
```

Now my question starts here:-
What I need to compare is from csv I get string like this

```
iPhone 5s-glittery or glittery-iPhone5s
```

and in the table from which i need to compare contains like this:-

```
iPhone 5s or iPhone 6s
```

so what I need is iPhone 5s is deleted and only I get string is glittery or whatever is there in string except for the phone model. My query is like this:-

```
var sku = 'iPhone 5s-glittery'; // assume that casesizemodel contains models:- iphone 5s, iphone 6s
            casesizemodel.findOne({model:new RegExp(sku,"i")},function(err,doc){})
```

but it doesn't return any doc.

Comment: 1. Just for reference Regex & text[ Search using mongoose with regex & text](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35812680/searching-in-mongo-db-using-mongoose-regex-vs-text)

Answer (score 0):

well I solved it myself, the best approach to do this is you do regular expression search:-
1. Fetch all the rows from corresponding table (the table from which string needs to be searched)

```
casesizemodel.find({},function(err,docs){});
```

2. Loop through all.
3. Use js search function and save:-

   sku.search(new RegExp(docs[i].modelname));