# JavaScript: Sentence variations using the reduce function

Tags: javascript, algorithm, reduce

For search purposes, given a string like `BBC Sport` I want to construct an array that looks like:

```
[ 'BBC', 'BB', 'B', 'Sport', 'Spor', 'Spo', 'Sp', 'S' ]
```

I've implenented it using 2 for loops:

```
const s     = "BBC sport";
const tags  = [];
const words = s.split(" ");

for (let word of words) {
  const wl = word.length;
  for (let i = 0; i < wl; i++) {
    tags.push(word.substr(0, wl - i));
  }
}

// tags now equals [ 'BBC', 'BB', 'B', 'Sport', 'Spor', 'Spo', 'Sp', 'S' ]
```

However, I'd like to implement it, if possible, with the reduce function instead of for loops.

How would you solve it?

Comment: Why do you need this array for *search purposes*?

Comment: Im searching using MongoDB, and this is a good way to implement a partial text search

Comment: I'm not familiar with mongodb but something like  `youStringField.includes(partialSearchText)` or a regex doesn't work?

Comment: It's too slow. look here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35812680/searching-in-mongo-db-using-mongoose-regex-vs-text

Comment: But searching for a string in an array will take more time and takes a lot of space per string field. And it doesn't support insensitive searches.

Comment: I can confirm it does support insensitive searches (I've verified it now). About the array issue. Not sure, but I can create a text field tags.join(" ") and it should solve it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Honestly I'd write the code the way you did. Two loops are readable, maintainable and fast.

If you really need a oneliner:

```
  s.split(" ").flatMap(word => Array.from(word, (_, i) => word.slice(0, i + 1)))
```

Comment: Oh, that's an interesting usage of `.from`, I didn't think about using it to init the array size. Clever, indeed.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a solution relying on function generators (which I would use) and a solution with `reduce` (as you asked) (which I wouldn't personally use), accepting an input string and a separator.

In your case, the separator is blankspace, of course, but it can be customized.

The below code will iterate through the input string and slice the relevant part of the string for each occurrence, by capitalizing it (since it looks like you are).

This should be elastic enough and, at the same time, easy to customize by eventually adding additional parameters to the `toTagList` method, or allowing further transformations since it's iterable.

```js
const s = "BBC sport";

function* toTagList(input, separator) {
  // split by the separator.
  for (const block of input.split(separator)) {
    // For each string block, split the whole word.
    var splitted = block.split('');
    // slice the input array by taking from the first character to the last one, then decrease to get only the previous portions of said word.
    for (var i = splitted.length; i > 0; i--) {
      // Finally, yield the capitalized string.
      yield capitalize(splitted.slice(0, i).join(''));
    }
  }
}
// this just capitalizes the string.
function capitalize(input) {
  return input.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + input.substring(1, input.length);
}

console.log([...toTagList(s, ' ')]);
```

If you really want to do that with reduce:

```js
const s = "BBC sport";

const tags = s.split(' ').reduce((acc, next) => {
  return acc.push(...Array.from({length: next.length}).map((_, i) => {
    return (next.split('').slice(0, i + 1)).join('')
  })), acc;
}, [])

console.log(tags);
```

Comment: Thanks, however your reduce map doesn't return my desired output. However it is a really nice solution

Comment: @YardenST do you want it to be capitalized or what? the reduce is returning the correct elements, not sure whether you want to sort that differently or have it capitalized, your sample isn't doing that either, that's why the reduce solution doesn't.

Comment: Not related to the capitalized issue. Just try to compare your output with mine, it is different. yours is an array of arrays, mine is array of strings

Comment: @YardenST ops, didn't notice that, I will fix that immediatly :P

Comment: @YardenST fixed, sorry for that, I didn't notice that while testing.